# MDX Calculate Difference of measure on Time Range end points

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

In my scenario I need to calculate Total Distance Covered, but in the data i get there is only the ***Total Distance Accumulated*** , so if i want to know what is total distance covered say in year 2012 i need to get :

*Total Distance Accumulated at END of Year 2012 - Total Distance Accumulated at END of Year 2012*

And I want this calculation to work on any level of the Date Dimension(which in this case is down to Day level), so a user can place it in a pivot table and just play with it as he sees fit.
I am not sure how or if i can do such a calculation member using MDX on the cube level.

Also, I'm working with **SQL 2008 Standard** addition, so no semi additive functions available.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Total Distance Travelled] as
(
SUM(CurrentDateMember([<hierarchy>],'["<hierarchy>"]\.[<DATE Level>]\.[yyyy-mm-dd]').lag(x):CurrentDateMember([Dates.Time],'["Dates.Time"]\.[Date]\.[yyyy-mm-dd]'),[Measures].[Total Distance Accumulated]))


Select {[Measures].[Total Distance Travelled]} On 1
from [<cube name>]
```

- 'x' here is number of days, If you are viewing across month level x would be no.of months
- This would basically sum the distance right from specified date